# on ubuntu 20.04 LTS the RENAME function does not work by pressing the F2 key for the files on the Desktop

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I also searched in the system Keyboard Shortcuts and it seems that there is a defect of this version ubuntu 20.04 LTS
  because the F2 key used to rename files does not appear anywhere in this list either

The easiest thing to notice is for files and directories directly on the Desktop!

I reinstalled ubuntu and it manifests itself in the same way!

I turned on ubuntu directly from the stick without installing it and the defect is identical!

But if I started from the NAUTILUS command line and navigated with NAUTILUS starting from the command line then I could rename the files and directories using the F2 key

Answer (score 1):

I just got a Lenovo ThinkPad and was having similar issues. I found that I had to go into the BIOS settings to configure the behavior of the function keys of the laptop's keyboard.